# Python JSON Parsing

Tags: python, json

Есть такой json

```
{'page': 1, 'total_pages': 63, 'per_page': 10}
```

Как мне с помощью питона получить, к примеру, значение переменной `per_page`?
С учетом что таких строк более ста, и все уникальные

А если такая строка, то как получить `permalink`?

```
{'page': 1, 'total_pages': 63, 'per_page': 10, '*': [{'flag': None, '*': None, '*': None, '*': None, 'like': None, '*': False, 'id': 51399328, 'type': '*::Simple', 'permalink': '*1212'}]}
```

Comment: JSON какой-то кривой у вас - одинарные кавычки не допускаются, а это скорее похоже на словарь в питоне

Comment: Очень надеюсь, что получилось донести до вас общий принцип.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, получилось, спасибо, но такая проблема, у меня есть переменная в файле, которая непостоянная, я сделал ветку if else на нее, но при её отсутствии не обрабатывается else, а выдается ошибка `KeyError: 'template'`, как мне вместо ошибки обрабатывать else?

Comment: @МолюскаМоллюсков хороший вопрос. Стоит опубликовать его именно как новый вопрос. Как опубликуете — кидайте ссылку сюда, я отвечу. (Либо кто-нибудь меня опередит).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Используйте модуль `json`. А ещё у вас невалидный JSON: в нем должны быть только двойные кавычки. Если их исправить, то сработает так:

```
import json

json_string = '{"page": 1, "total_pages": 63, "per_page": 10}'

data = json.loads(json_string)
print(data['per_page'])
```

Как верно замечает выше mymedia, эта структура очень похожа на словарь, сериализованный в строку.
Чтобы десериализовать его обратно, можно использовать `ast`:

```
import ast

serialized_dict = "{'page': 1, 'total_pages': 63, 'per_page': 10}"

data = ast.literal_eval(serialized_dict)
print(data['per_page'])
```

> А если такая строка, то как получить permalink

В результате сериализации вы получаете обычный словарь Python, содержащий в себе разные строки, списки и другие словари. Доставать элементы можно по тому же принципу: `['ключ словаря'][номер в списке]['еще ключ'][...]`.

Давайте отформатируем ваш объект и присмотримся к нему:

```
{
    'page': 1,
    'total_pages': 63,
    'per_page': 10,
    '*': [
        {
            'flag': None,
            '*': None,
            '*': None,
            '*': None,
            'like': None,
            '*': False,
            'id': 51399328,
            'type': '*::Simple',
            'permalink': '*1212'
        }
    ]
}
```

Например, в вашем объекте-словаре есть ключ `'*'`, нам нужно значение по этому ключу. Это `data['*']`.

Это значение — список. В этом списке нам нужен первый элемент. Достаем его по индексу `0`: `data['*'][0]`.

Этот первый элемент — снова словарь. В нём нам нужно значение по ключу `'permalink'`. Получается так:

```
print(data['*'][0]['permalink'])
```

Answer (score 6):

В вашем примере приведён не JSON, а словарь из Python. Для разбора такой строки можно воспользоваться безопасной функцией [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

```
import ast
s = "{'page': 1, 'total_pages': 63, 'per_page': 10, '*': [{'flag': None, '*': None, '*': None, '*': None, 'like': None, '*': False, 'id': 51399328, 'type': '*::Simple', 'permalink': '*1212'}]}"
obj = ast.literal_eval(s)
print(obj['*'][0]['permalink'])
```